# unix file date conversion from %m/%d/%Y

Tags: date, unix, awk, sed

On a unix server, I have a file which has data in following format:

```
4/1/2014,text1,text2,text3,text4
4/1/2014,....
...
...
4/20/2014,text1,text2,text3,text4
4/21/2014,...
...
...
10/14/2014,text1,text2,text3,text4
10/15/2014,...
...
...
```

This complete file needs to be converted in following format:

```
2014-04-01,text1,text2,text3,text4
2014-04-01,....
...
...
2014-04-20,text1,text2,text3,text4
2014-04-21,...
...
...
2014-10-14,text1,text2,text3,text4
2014-10-15,...
...
...
```

Kindly advise some solution onto this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F, '{split($1,a,"/");$1=a[3]"-"sprintf("%02d",a[1])"-"sprintf("%02d",a[2])}1' OFS=, file
2014-04-01,text1,text2,text3,text4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '\#^[0-9]\{1,2\}/[0-9]\{1,2\}/[0-9]\{4\}# {
        s#^\([^/]*\)/#0\1-0#;s#/#-#
        s/^0*\([0-9]\{2\}-\)0*\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\3-\1\2,/
        }' YourFile
```

just reformat and treat the extra 0 if needed, with a filter (optionnal if all line have this) to limit on this starting date)